# How to enqueue child theme css file at the end of <head> element

Tags: css, wordpress

Basically I want to load my child's theme css file at the end of  element to avoid override of other stylesheets.
At this moment my css file is overridden by builder, which has some sort of bug with responsive design so I wanted to apply certain styles myself.
I tried to lookup for solution online, but could not find anything.
Anybody here has had same issue with it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use here priority. we add the priority 99. so it will likely be last but some plugins may add CSS at a higher priority, though it's rare. so please check once this code I am truly sure this works for you.

```
function custom_enqueue_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style('customcss',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```